# UICollectionView equal cell spacing

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, tvos

I am displaying several images in a collection view. They are all the same orientation (landscape) except for one, which is portrait (see image below):

[image]

I am trying to make the portrait image more centered, so that everything is evenly spaced. Any ideas on how to do this?

PhotoGalleryViewController.swift:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return images.count
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! PhotoGalleryCell

    let image = UIImage(named: images[indexPath.row])
    cell.imageView.image = image
    cell.captionLabel.text = captions[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                    sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    var size = CGSize()

    if (indexPath.row == 3)
    {
        size = CGSize(width: 450, height: 600)
    }
    else {
        size = CGSize(width: 940, height: 600)

    }
    return size
}
```

Comment: It looks like you just need to adjust content mode of the image view or your auto layout constraints. If you could show us the code/xib for setting up the layout of the cells it would be easier for us to help out.

Comment: It will be great if you update your question with CollectionView Delegate Methods , cellspacing issue is there .

Comment: I added the code example, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be not altering the cell size based on the fact that a portrait image will be in item 3.

Instead update the layout of your cell so that whatever image it gets assigned to it's image view, it will centre the image in itself and centralise the label underneath the image.

Comment: If I don't alter the cell size, the image is automatically stretched to be the same size as the others. Is there another way to do it without using sizeForItemAtIndexPath?

Comment: If you change the `contentMode` of the image view on the cell to `.scaleToFit`, the image should no longer stretch.

Comment: Oh, I can't believe I didn't think of that. Got it now. Thanks!

Comment: Not a problem :D

Answer (score 0):

In ViewDidLoad method put this code :

```
  let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
  layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: 20)
  layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
  layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
  collectionview.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

Also add this into cellForRow Methods:

```
cell.imageview.contentmode = .aspectfit
```

Hope it helps to resolve your issue.